# How to create parallel inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say I have an inheritance hierarchy. For the demonstration purposes I will use C# and animal hierarchy:

```
abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;

    public Color MainColor;

    public virtual bool HasColor(Color color)
    {
        return MainColor == color;
    }
}
    
abstract class CarnivorousAnimal : Animal
{
    public int Damage;

    public List<Color> SecondaryColors;

    public override bool HasColor(Color color)
    {
        return base.HasColor(color) || SecondaryColors.Contains(color);
    }
}
    
class Cat : CarnivorousAnimal
{
    public float MeowLoudness;

    public Color FurColor;

    public override bool HasColor(Color color)
    {
        return base.HasColor(color) || FurColor == color;
    }
}
```

And now I want to move all of the data and methods related to animal coloring to a separate parallel AnimalData hierarchy (*AnimalColorData, CarnivorousAnimalColorData, CatColorData*) under fields called *ColorData* to comply with SRP. The color data will look like this:

```
class AnimalColorData
{
    public Color MainColor;

    public virtual bool HasColor(Color color)
    {
        return MainColor == color;
    }
}

class CarnivorousAnimalColorData : AnimalColorData
{
    public List<Color> SecondaryColors;

    public override bool HasColor(Color color)
    {
        return base.HasColor(color) || SecondaryColors.Contains(color);
    }
}

class CatColorData : CarnivorousAnimalColorData
{
    public Color FurColor;

    public override bool HasColor(Color color)
    {
        return base.HasColor(color) || FurColor == color;
    }
}
```

And the resulting animal hierarchy should look like this:

```
abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;
    public AnimalColorData ColorData;
}

abstract class CarnivorousAnimal : Animal
{
    public int Damage;
    public CarnivorousAnimalColorData ColorData;
}

class Cat : CarnivorousAnimal
{
    public float MeowLoudness;
    public CatColorData ColorData;
}
```

How do I do this properly without hiding the base *ColorData* fields? This code won't work because I will have 3 copies of ColorData field in *Cat* class. I want to be able to take any instance of a Cat and get its color data like this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.ColorData.MainColor = Color.green;
cat.ColorData.FurColor = Color.cyan;

CarnivorousAnimal animal = cat;
Console.WriteLine(animal.ColorData.HasColor(Color.cyan)); //false

Console.WriteLine(cat.ColorData.HasColor(Color.cyan)); //true
```

Using generic types would be suboptimal, because I will have to specify the type each time I want to use a base class.

Answer (score 1):

I can only see 3 possible approaches here:

1st option: create a separate filed/property for each `ColorData` type:

```
abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;
    public AnimalColorData ColorData;
}

abstract class CarnivorousAnimal : Animal
{
    public int Damage;
    public CarnivorousAnimalColorData CarnivorousColorData;
}

class Cat : CarnivorousAnimal
{
    public float MeowLoudness;
    public CatColorData AnimalColorData;
}
```

Apparently, not only it looks ugly, but also may cause some information duplication issues (since both `CatColorData AnimalColorData` and `AnimalColorData ColorData` contain information about the main color) and highly coupled code.

2nd option: leave the `ColorData` field in the `Animal` class without generics:

```
abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;
    public AnimalColorData ColorData;
}

abstract class CarnivorousAnimal : Animal
{
    public int Damage;
}

class Cat : CarnivorousAnimal
{
    public float MeowLoudness;
}
```

So that you can pass any suitable `AnimalColorData` instance (or its inheritors) to your ```Cat`` object.

Why may it be not the best approach? Well, since we can pass any `AnimalColorData` instance, it may be `AnimalColorData`, `CarnivorousAnimalColorData` or `CatColorData` or even `DogColorData` as you don't force any concrete type of `AnimalColorData`.

How can we solve it? With our 3rd option:

```
abstract class Animal<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : AnimalColorData
{
    public int Health;
    public T ColorData;
}

abstract class CarnivorousAnimal<T> : Animal<T> where T : CarnivorousAnimalColorData
{
    public int Damage;
}

class Cat : CarnivorousAnimal<T> :  CarnivorousAnimal<T> where T : CatColorData
{
    public float MeowLoudness;
}
```

Here we create an obligation to pass `AnimalColorData` instance to an `Animal` object, `CarnivorousAnimalColorData` to a `CarnivorousAnimal` object and `CatColorData` to a `Cat` object.

You cannot pass a `DogColorData` to a `Cat` instance.

Moreover, `Animal` with `CatColorData` as its `ColorData` field will handle it as if has just `MainColor` as public filed, while `HasColor` just as you intended.

What are the cons of this approach?

1. It provides some additional complexity.
2. Imagine, that we have not only `ColorData`, but also
   `SoundData`, `BehaviorData` etc. Now we would have to specify not 1, but 3 generic types for each of `Data`.

Obviously, the final choice is up to you, but in you specific case I`d prefer the 3rd option with generics.

Comment: Amazing! A very thought-out response. All your ways to accomplish this are great. Meanwhile I found another way that I went with. I have shared it in my answer to my own question

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way to do this. All of the ColorData code stays the same but the Animal classes would look something like this:

```
abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;

    public abstract AnimalColorData AnimalColorData { get; }
}

abstract class CarnivorousAnimal : Animal
{
    public int Damage;

    public override AnimalColorData AnimalColorData => CarnivorousColorData;
    public abstract CarnivorousAnimalColorData CarnivorousColorData { get; }
}

class Cat : CarnivorousAnimal
{
    public float MeowLoudness;

    public override CarnivorousAnimalColorData CarnivorousColorData => CatColorData;
    public CatColorData CatColorData;
}
```

As you can see, there is only one instance of a ColorData class in a Cat class. But all of the other forms of it in base classes are just properties that point to the CatColorData class.